# Getting output from ssh with BufferedReader

Tags: java, ssh, bufferedreader

I'm using the following script to execute commands and get output:
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

```
static Runtime rt;
static Process proc;

public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] commands = {"ssh.exe","-o BatchMode=yes",  "root@192.168.1.1", "cat /var/a.txt"};
    //  String[] commands = {"ssh.exe", "root@192.168.0.1"};
    //  String[] commands = { "ls", "-la" };

    proc = rt.exec(commands);

    new Thread("out") {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + getName() + " running");
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            String s = null;
            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("StdOut:\n");
            try {
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("$ " + s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }.start();

    new Thread("err") {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + getName() + " running");
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

            String s = null;
            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("StdErr:\n");
            try {
                while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("! " + s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();




    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("end");

}
```

If I execute "ls -la" or "ssh" I get the expected output. However, attempting to get a.txt content from remote device (line 1) fails and the operation hangs.
Executing "ssh root@192.168.0.1 cat a.txt" from command line works and retrieves the content.

Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to read the two streams in separate threads, or merge them. You can't assume that the process will exit and therefore close its `stderr` before writing anything to `stdtout`, or rather without writing so little to `stdout` that it won't block.

Comment: Update the code in the Question to show us how you did that.

Comment: You may also need to close the process's input stream.